# Copying an AD user with New-ADUser -Instance from Get-ADUser returns cannot convert value error

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to copy an AD user account as part of a larger script. It has worked in the past but is currently throwing this error:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'Instance'. Cannot convert value "CN=Test Tester,OU=etc..." to type
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser". Error: "Cannot convert the "CN=Test Tester,OU=etc..."
value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser" to type
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser"
```

The relevant code:

```
$user_to_copy = test.tester
$user_to_copy_instance = Get-ADUser $user_to_copy

New-ADUser -Instance $user_to_copy_instance
```

I don't understand why it throws an error when trying to convert the value type as I'm following the documentation for the "-Instance" parameter as found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser?view=win10-ps

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I see the type `Deserialized` in there. How are you using the Active Directory module `import-module ActiveDirectory`? Are you connected to a remote session to do this? Problem is you are not providing the object expected. I get this when I am working remotely with a Exchange snap in for example.

Comment: You don't get the instance anyhow from a remote PowerShell session? The `Deserialized` type definitely looks like that would be the case, and reason you lose the type information.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running this in a remote session. When you get an object back from the server, because it went through serialization and deserialization, it's not really that object anymore. It's a "property bag": just the properties, but without the methods that go along with the real type. You can read more about that [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2010/01/07/how-objects-are-sent-to-and-from-remote-sessions/) if you'd like.

To avoid that, you can try running both commands in the same line:

```
New-ADUser -Instance (Get-ADUser $user_to_copy)
```

I don't know 100% that it will work, but it makes sense that it might.

Comment: I haven't tested that but it makes sense. In the end I just grabbed all the properties I was trying to copy using Get-ADUser into separate variables and assigned them to the new account using the Set-ADUser parameters such as: $department_to_copy = (Get-ADUser $user_to_copy -Properties department).department -> -Department $department_to_copy